# How to read value of variable, where the name of variable is the value of another variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I think an example is in order. Consider I have these two environment variables setup (by a Continuous Delivery tool): `PACKAGE_VER=1.2.3` and `USE_VERSION_FROM=PACKAGE_VER`.

What I want now is a script that can't predict the name of the variable pointing out `1.2.3`, only `USE_VERSION_FROM`. And so, I'm looking for a way to get my script to know the version to use (`1.2.3`) without knowing anything other than that `USE_VERSION_FROM` points out the name of the variable that holds the version number.

My naïve non-working first attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION_TO_USE="${${USE_VERSION_FROM}}"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
PACKAGE_VER=1.2.3
USE_VERSION_FROM=PACKAGE_VER
VERSION_TO_USE=${!USE_VERSION_FROM}
echo $VERSION_TO_USE
```

```
1.2.3
```

This is "indirect parameter expansion" as described in [the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Note, it's not strictly necessary to provide quotes on a variable assignment `a=$b` vs `a="$b"` -- word splitting is not performed during an assignment (can't find the reference for that just now)